# How to remove the lines that have empty fields?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a CSV file with multiple columns, comma ", " separated and numbers of lines.
some lines have empty one or two fields "Columns". How I can identify in a separate file and/or remove those line with one or more empty columns with **Awk** command.

example

```
aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,
,bbbb,cccc,dddd,
aaaa,,cccc,dddd,
aaaa,,,dddd,
,,,dddd,
```

The ", ," means empty columns.
I tried this command but it did not work!

```
awk -F, '$1,4~/^$/' filename
```

The expected output should be only :

aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd,

Comment: can you add expected output for the sample given? can you particularly clarify is trailing comma in a line mean empty field?

Comment: Seems like the last field in all those lines is empty. Is an empty line to be considered as a line with no field or a line with one empty field?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==""){next}}1' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller (`mlr`)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and its [`filter`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-dsl-filter-statements/) sub-command to discard each record that contains at least one empty field:

```bash
mlr --csv -N filter 'for (k,v in $*) { is_empty(v) { false; break } true }' file.csv
```

This reads the data as header-less CSV. The `for` loop runs for each record, and the `filter` operation discards the record immediately if `is_empty(v)` returns *true*.

Given the test data in the question, the command given here would output nothing as each record contains at least one empty field.

Would you only want to examine the first four fields, use a test on `k` to make sue you only test those four first fields for emptiness:

```bash
mlr --csv -N filter 'for (k,v in $*) { k <= 4 && is_empty(v) { false; break } true }' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's a simple CSV file (no quoting, no header, no multiline field):

```
perl -F, -e 'print unless grep {$_ eq ""} @F[0..3]' your-file
```

Would remove the lines where any of the first to fourth fields is empty (as your awk attempt suggests you want to do).

While compact, that code redundantly checks all the 4 fields even though it could stop checking as soon as it finds one empty.

```
awk -F, '$1 != "" && $2 != "" && $3 != "" && $4 != ""' file.csv
```

Even if less compact wouldn't have the *problem*.

Note that both remove lines that have fewer than four fields.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just drop any line with two commas that are adjacent or separated only by whitespace, or that are first on the line? Something like:

```
 [dynamic<1>butlet]tmp $ cat data2
aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,
,bbbb,cccc,dddd,
aaaa,,cccc,dddd,
aaaa,,,dddd,
,,,dddd,

 $ egrep -v ',[ ^I]*,|^[ ^I]*,' data2
aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.put unless grep {.chars == 0}, .split(",")[0..*-2]'  file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne 'given .split(",", :skip-empty) {.join(",").put if .elems > 3}'  file
```

The first answer above is very similar to the Perl answer given by @StéphaneChazelas (Thank you, Stéphane!). Since the lines end with a comma (which can be interpreted as a trailing blank column), the index `[0..*-2]` is used which drops this last (empty) element. This code retains rows with all filled columns (excepting the final empty column) and will drop lines if blank columns are found *even after* the first 4 fields.  Use `.split(",")[0..3]` if you want to restrict the requirement to the first four fields (elements).

Note, `*-1` is the last element of an array-like structure in Raku, while something like `[0..*]` also works (means *'give me everything'*). Raku has "Zen slices" as well, so `.split(",")[]` is valid syntax.

The second answer uses the fact that Raku's `split` routine has a `:skip-empty` parameter (i.e. "adverb") which can take the place of `grep`ping for `.chars == 0`. So you are left with deciding how many columns are required in the output. Here `.elems > 3` asks for a minimum of 4 columns.

Technically, the second answer is the correct answer, because the first answer leaves the trailing comma in place, while the second answer removes it.

Sample Input:

```
aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,
,bbbb,cccc,dddd,
aaaa,,cccc,dddd,
aaaa,,,dddd,
,,,dddd,
```

Sample Output (first answer):

```
aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,
```

Sample Output (second answer):

```
aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org